# Flutter how to receive images from other apps

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to learn Flutter app development. My use case is any image shared by other android apps such as photo gallery apps to my app, I want to upload those images to cloud and delete images from internal storage immediately. I am using receive_sharing_intent page to receive image intents from other apps. Problem is during sharing, image is being copied to cache dir and that cached image path is given to my app. But I want the original image path from the internal storage so that I can delete it after the upload. What should I do to get original image path from internal storage when other apps share image intent with my app? Can anyone help me out what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I've used this package [receive_sharing_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent)

Package description: A flutter plugin that enables flutter apps to receive sharing photos, videos, text, urls or any other file types from another app.